# Is there a Github webhook event for when a Project you've Forked gets Updated?

Tags: github, github-api, webhooks

I'm looking for a way to get a Webhook on someone else's repository so that when it gets updated I get a web request like if it was my own.

I had the idea of forking the project for myself and then adding a webhook so that when the upstream gets updated I can get a notification. However, it doesn't appear like any of the event options can do this.

Am I missing something?
Here's the github event page by the way: https://developer.github.com/webhooks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing any event: the usual solution is to ask the upstream repo maintainer to [add your email to the email service notification](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-notifications-for-pushes-to-a-repository/), in order to receive an email for each commit pushed.

The other alternative (if you cannot register any webservice directly on the upstream repo) is to set up a polling service doing a regular pull of the upstream repo and sending you a notification.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the reply, that was my 2nd alternative that I went ahead and did. I thought it would be slightly more efficient this way though.